# How ResNet researchers achieve high accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

I tried to recreate the [original ResNet 50](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf) model myself, using all the same layers, hyperparameters, and data augmentation methods mentioned in the paper. (I only trained on a few hundred iterations as opposed to 64k iterations that the authors did, so that's the one difference.) However, when I try training on CIFAR-10 (classification), the model achieved 93% accuracy on train set, but only 73% on the validation set. The ResNet paper, on the other hand, seems to suggest a 90%+ test accuracy:

[image]

Even when I tried different hyperparameters, I wasn't able get anywhere near that number. So, my question is how did the authors achieve such high performance, when I in fact, recreated the same network?

Comment: Reproducibility of machine learning research is a thorny problem. It's possible, even plausible, that they tuned some other model parameters and simply forgot to mention it in the paper. My recommendation is to try and track down any published code, Github repository, or other resource from the researchers themselves. If that fails, you'll have to look for other researchers' replications (but these might be imperfect).

Comment: Here's the [Papers with Code page for the paper](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/deep-residual-learning-for-image-recognition). There's a number of implementations with widespread utilization. I'd start by comparing your model and approach to those implementations.

Comment: If you are using pytorch, here is a github repository that can help you reproduce some of the resnet results on CIFAR-10 : https://github.com/kuangliu/pytorch-cifar